# Mac Super Slow Diagnosis

Tags: memory, performance

My mac is *super* slow and I'm not sure why.

Typing in a text edit document sometimes takes ~1s to display what I just typed in.

While I do have a lot of applications open, I'm not seeing signs of system stress. If it's not CPU or memory, what could it be?

[image]
[image]

Applications Open/Jobs on the Computer

- ~ 96 open text edit docs
- ~ 10 chrome windows - maybe 5 tabs each
- ~ 2 terminal windows
- ~ 20 desktop screenshots
- ~ Battery at 24% and charging

**Machine Specs**
2015 MacBook Pro, 2.7 GHz Dual-Core Intel i5, 8GB 1867 MHz DDR3 w/~120 GB of flash storage

Comment: I'd bet with such a huge number of files open in relatively few apps, you're seeing a lot of swap & memory compression. Also… what OS & how full is the drive? 120GB drives are very easy to choke, making any swaps much slower.

Comment: What is swap and memory compression? OS is Big Sur (not enough space to upgrade). Drive only has 15G left on it.

Comment: I do notice it seems to get better once I close all the text docs. Is there any way I could have used metrics from activity monitor to diagnose that vs. just figuring it out by playing around?

Comment: It's just a 'learn on the job' 'rule of thumb', 'no specific guideline' but you 'learn over time' kind of 'feel'. [& more trite memes as & when I think of them ;)

Comment: Surely there must be a way to measure, dig in, and diagnose if I *really* wanted to get into the guts of my computer right?

Comment: No, because memory management is *waaaay* down in the guts of the OS. All you can really know is that having 96 documents open in one app simultaneously is going to be a 'bad idea' on such a RAM-limited machine.

Comment: My confusion is that RAM wasn't listed as high in my screenshot. Wouldn't the RAM fill up first, report being full, then fall back to other types of memory?

Comment: No. Memory management doesn't work that way. Honestly, I don't understand it all, it's waaay too complex. Just know that 96 open documents is never a good move.

Comment: No worries :) I get the 96 text doc thing - it just made me curious to learn more about how my computer works.